# Can I use only certain subtensors in Pytorch Tensor in training process?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

For example, I have Pytorch Tensor with size (B, 4, H, W) and I want to use only certain subtensors from axis 1 (with indexes 0 and 3, to be specific) for model in training process. Remaining two subtensors will not be used in training.

Of course, I can change tensor to have (B, 2, H, W) size, but I'm curious about what if I will use original tensor, will be training and inference process still stable?

Comment: So wouldn't this come down to setting the batch size to 2?

Comment: Yes, sure, just index the tensor before passing to the model. Or is this tensor a model parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly! This approach is commonly used to handle specific components of data in separate ways. For example:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
B, C, H, W = 100, 4, 224, 224
inputs = torch.randn(B, C, H, W)
    
class model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(2, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(2, 2, 3, 1, 1)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = x[:, :2, ...]
        x2 = x[:, 2:, ...]
        res1 = self.conv1(x1)
        res2 = self.conv2(x2)
        res = torch.cat([res1, res2], dim=1)
        return res
    
my_model = model()
res = my_model(inputs)
res.shape
```